# babel-plugin-transform-object-assign or babel-polyfill?

Tags: internet-explorer, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, mobx-state-tree

I am using webpack 4, mobx state tree and babel. When I run mobx state tree I get this error on IE 11

```
{exception} Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'
in mobx-state-tree.module.js

   var name = opts.name || defaultObjectOptions.name;
        // TODO: this test still needed?
        if (!/^\w[\w\d_]*$/.test(name))
            fail("Typename should be a valid identifier: " + name);
        **Object.assign(_this, defaultObjectOptions, opts);**
        // ensures that any default value gets converted to its related type
        _this.properties = toPropertiesObject(_this.properties);
        freeze(_this.properties); // make sure nobody messes with it
        return _this;
    }
stack "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'\n at ModelType$$1 (eval code:3080:9)\n at model$$1 (eval code:3349:5)\n at eval code (eval code:9:1)\n at ./src/stores/AppStore.js (http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:2136:1)\n at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:710:12)\n at fn (http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:95:13)\n at eval code (eval code:9:1)\n at ./src/stores/Stores.js (http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:2148:1)\n at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:710:12)\n at fn (http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:95:13)"
```

I am not sure if I should be using [babel pollyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) or [babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-assign/) or something different.

Comment: babel polyfill should work, it'll also polyfill other unsupported methods in IE